# Seemless compatibility elementaryOS 6.1 with any ultrabooks

Tags: drivers, hardware

I want to replace my old Macbook Pro from 2012 by a more recent ultrabook and I want to stick with elementaryOS. So I'm not searching the best OS for the hardware, but the other way round. Due to my experiences about missing drivers / unsupported hardware parts:

- Can anybody recommend a powerful ultrabook that runs seemlessly with eOS 6.1?
- ... even "out of the box" (with installation defaults) ?
- Would you say that non-Apple hardware is supported better?

Note: I have found this [Ubuntu compatibility chart](https://ubuntu.com/certified/laptops?q=&limit=20&release=20.04%20LTS), which I can set to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (underlying elementaryOS 6.1) and check for Dell, HP and Lenovo. Do you know any more sources?

(I was going to ask this question in the [forum](https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?register/register), but the forum told me to ask here first.)

Answer (score 1):

I just got this [Asus Zenbook 14 Oled](https://www.asus.com/uk/Laptops/For-Home/Zenbook/Zenbook-14-OLED-UX3402-12th-Gen-Intel) with the Intel processor

Installed latest daily build of Elementary 7 - two things don't work as well:

1. Speakers don't work at all - see https://superuser.com/questions/1719920/no-sound-from-internal-speakers-on-laptop-but-headphone-jack-and-hdmi-works?newreg=dc433c45a939461e91fccdbf0862f223
2. Battery is 4hrs with `5.15.0-52-generic` kernel. People comment that with 5.16 and 5.17 kernel battery usage is considerably better, but yeah

Else, it's a nice machine; keyboard is nice. Coming from an M1 Mac before.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using elementary OS with a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon for the last 5 years. Before that I was on a MacBook Pro with Mac OS. It pretty much just works. It's my daily driver for personal work. I still use Mac OS at the office due to IT restrictions. I bought  gen 3 X1 carbon refurbished from Lenovo back in the day, installed elementary OS from day 1 and haven't looked back. If you stick to somewhat older hardware (2-3 years old) you should be fine. You can always dual boot for a while to make sure everything works the way you want it. I wiped Windows as soon as I got the machine. No regrets.